# How to get all returned lines with each oracle errror message into one variable using perl

Tags: perl, oracle, error-handling, variables, return-value

How do i get all of the lines of `"$dblink is down"` into one `$l_msg` string?

Ideally I would like to get the error returned by oracle on failure and I cannot see a way to solve this.

```
my $dblinks = $l_dbh->selectcol_arrayref("select dbname from db_link"); 
for my $dblink (@$dblinks) { 
  my $l_results = eval { 
    my ($l_erg) = $l_dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT dummy||'OK' " 
      . $l_dbh->quote_identifier($dblink, undef, "dual") ); 
    $l_erg; 
  }; 
   while (@l_row = $l_results->fetchrow_array) {
    $l_erg=$l_row[0];
    if ($l_results !~ /XOK/) { 
      @l_errstr=();
      l_msg="$dblink is down with @l_errstr"
      #  dblink45667 is down with ORA-12154"

    } else { 
      say "$dblink is is up"; 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: @Paul: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have reformatted the code in your question (select and press Ctrl+K to display it as code).

Answer (score 2):

How about concatenating them to a variable outside of the loop:

```
my $dblinks = $l_dbh->selectcol_arrayref("select dbname from db_link"); 
my $l_msg = '';
for my $dblink (@$dblinks) { 
  my $l_results = eval { 
    my ($l_erg) = $l_dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT dummy||'OK' " 
      . $l_dbh->quote_identifier($dblink, undef, "dual") ); 
    $l_erg; 
  }; 
   while (@l_row = $l_results->fetchrow_array) {
    $l_erg=$l_row[0];
    if ($l_results !~ /XOK/) { 
      @l_errstr=();
      l_msg .= "$dblink is down with @l_errstr"
      #  dblink45667 is down with ORA-12154"

    } else { 
      say "$dblink is is up"; 
    } 
  }
}
```